# How to display number of item in Ember.js template?

Tags: ember.js

I can display data from object like this:

```
 <ul>
  {{#each people}}
    <li>Hello, {{name}}!</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

But i would want to add the number of the record like this:

```
<ul>
  {{#each people}}
    {{NUMBER_OF_PERSON}} <li>Hello, {{name}}!</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

How to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by `number of person` it's ID? or the total number of persons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean display an index. Currently you need to use a handlebars helper. This gist shows an example https://gist.github.com/burin/1048968 scrolling through the comments it looks like there are several approaches.

Handlebars has @index and @key, but currently these do now work with emberjs.

Answer (score 1):

In the controller, you can write a function like this:

```
no_of_person: function(){
                 return this._parentView.contentIndex;
              }.property('people')
```

In the template, `{{no_of_person}}` will show the index number of the record.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS Counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters). It works for tables too. Here's an example taken from MDN:

```css
ul {
  counter-reset: section;                /* Creates a new instance of the
                                            section counter with each ol
                                            element */
  list-style-type: none;
}

li:before {
  counter-increment: section;            /* Increments only this instance
                                            of the section counter */
  content: counters(section,".") " ";    /* Adds the value of all instances
                                            of the section counter separated
                                            by a ".". */
}
```